# Need to extract a specific text node to hide or remove it using JQuery

Tags: jquery, text, extract

I have a blog on WordPress that I have control over in order to edit and format the RSS feed content. I have another website on which I want to display the excerpts of the posts from my blog, then link to the blog directly for the full post. The feed I am getting is fine except I have some unwanted untagged text displaying, and because it has no HTML tags I can't use CSS to hide it. (I appreciate that I also need to debug the feed and probably the blog content, as the feed code I'm using doesn't give this error on any other blogs I've set up, but that's a separate issue).

This is the format of the HTML that is being generated from the feed:

```
        <li class="rss-item">
      <a class="rss-item" href="http://myblog.com/post-title">Post Title</a>
      <br>
      http://myblog.com/post-title/Post Title <!-- this line I want to remove -->
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <a href="#">
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="excerpt">Excerpt text</div>
      <a href="http://myblog.com/post-title">Continue reading...</a>
    </li>
```

I wish to extract the text node for the untagged text (which displays the URL and Post Title on the page) and either remove it using JQuery, or add some span tags and hide it using CSS. My JQuery knowledge is very limited, and I have tried to edit various bits of code I've found online without success. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tn = $('a.rss-item[href="http://myblog.com/post-title"] + br')[0].nextSibling;

tn.parentNode.removeChild( tn );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/BZ5Tx/

This finds the `br` element whose previous sibling is the `a` element with the `rss-item` class and the href `http://myblog.com/post-title`.

Then it extracts the DOM element, gets the `nextSibling` which should be the text node, and stores it in a variable.

Then from the text node, get the `parentNode` and use `removeChild` to remove the text node.

---

If this is a repeating pattern with different urls, you can try this selector instead:

```
$('a.rss-item[href] + br');
```

...and use a loop:

```
$('a.rss-item[href] + br').each(function() {

    var tn = this.nextSibling;

    tn.parentNode.removeChild( tn );

});
```

---

As noted by [@Anurag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165737/anurag), it's a good idea to do a loop at each location, removing text nodes until a non text node is reached, just in case there are adjacent text nodes.

```
$('a.rss-item[href] + br').each(function() {

    var tn = this;

    while( tn = tn.nextSibling  ) {
        if( tn.nodeType === 3 ) {
            tn.parentNode.removeChild( tn );
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I edited your answer to remove the [href...] text, as this link will vary from post to post. The unwanted text was removed on the first post display (hooray), but not the others - this is a page displaying the latest 10 posts. Is there a loop I need to use here?

Comment: +1 nice answer - another addition I would suggest is to loop over and remove `nextSibling` nodes till we keep seeing text nodes.

Comment: @patrick dw... just seen your notes about the loop... works a TREAT! Many thanks!

Comment: @AndyiBM: You're welcome. Note that I just gave another update based on the suggestion from @Anurag to cover the possibility of adjacent text nodes. Anyway, glad it worked out. :o)

Comment: Actually @partrick, just tried your update and it un-fixed it :( I'm happy going back to the first loop code, as for my instance the text I need to remove is pretty consistent.

Comment: @AndyiBM: Well that's odd. I'll have to research that later. Anyway, I updated it to move the `nodeType` test into the statement block for the `while`, and it works. Whichever you prefer. :o)

Comment: ...Ah, I know what it was. I needed to wrap the assignment in parentheses to ensure that the assignment takes place before the full `&&` expression. `while( (tn = tn.nextSibling) && tn.nodeType === 3 ) {` This is because `&&` has higher precedence than `=`.